# Hierarchical list for selecting an element

Tags: website-design, web-app, mobile-web, hierarchy, mobile-first

The user is trying to select an element which will be used in a form. So it could be like selecting interests in an app where you can pick the more general case (e.g. sports) or the more specific (e.g. baseball).

I have hierarchical data where:
* Exactly one node may be selected.
* Users can select nodes anywhere in the tree
* Leaf nodes *must* be selectable
* Parent nodes *may* be selectable. Selecting a parent node represents a selection of all of its leaf node descendants.
* Selectable parent nodes are uncommon.
* The depth of the data is deeper than can be readily shown on the screen all at once.

I am developing an interface for browsing this data. This data needs to be usable on both desktop and mobile interfaces on the web.

I am thinking of modeling an interface after what Apple does with hierarchical menus, like the one below. The differences in my case are primarily that:
* The items can have three states: selectable node, refinable node, and nodes with both capabilities. **How do I make this look uncluttered?**
* My design must operate reasonably on both desktop and mobile. **How do I design the refinement signifier in an unobtrusive way that is clear even on desktop views.**
* My lists have a lot of heterogenous content. This happens only rarely in Apple menus, like the shut down button in the second screenshot. **How do I show heterogenous content without looking disjoint?**
[image: iOS settings menu]

Notice the blue row at the bottom representing differing content.
[image: iOS shut down screen]

What I've been thinking of so far is similar to the Apple design. These next two screenshots show the top level of the hierarchy here, and...
[image: Top level of hierarchy]

...the screen after *food* is selected.
[image: Refinement of hierarchy]

I like the multi-screen approach to this design for my use case, so I am primarily looking for feedback on exactly what icons/buttons to put in, and how to separate out content. I'm particularly interested in examples on the web and high fidelity mock examples, but I'm open to lower fidelity feedback as well.

The one structural thing that I think could be changed is in the combination case where a parent node can also be selected. Conceptually I've illustrated it here:
[image: Alternate design to combination case]

I'd like to draw attention to the fact that this makes the rows less crowded, and seem more homogenous. But I'm not sure exactly how to design the *current level* selection mechanism. **How could I clearly indicate that the current level can be selected? Relatedly, how do I indicate the situation where the current level *can't* be selected?**

Comment: Probably be more useful to under stand the use case for this design, what is the user trying to do?

Comment: The user is trying to select an element which will be used in a form. So it could be like selecting interests in an app where you can pick the more general case (e.g. sports) or the more specific (e.g. baseball). The hierarchy can get as deep as ~8 levels though.

Comment: And how many total, potential options? Can they select more than one?

Comment: They can only select one option. Selecting an option returns them to the form with the item selected.

Comment: 8 levels deep to select a singular item could be quite a frustrating experience for your users, do they know what they are searching for?

Comment: I've done some optimizations to cut down on how deep the data can go, so I'm not actually sure what the real maximum depth will be. Typically the depth looks to be at most 3 I believe. They know what they're searching for, and I have a top-level search implemented that filters those results – the top level has around 1000 items. Then they narrow down these categories. A couple more complex examples: [top] -> [13 items], and another goes [top] -> [2 items] -> [3 items].

Comment: I may find reasons to remove the filters later on, so I'd like the UI to be capable of handling 8 levels, but right now I think 3 might be the max depth, or at least most items fit within that size.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments, given what you have said, I would not use a tree hierarchy. As your users know what they are looking for and there is the potential for so many items, I would use a type-ahead search, that returns results as the user type and they can select the right one when it appears.

I suggested this for a similar query posted about a medical app, the idea is principally the same.

[image]

Comment: I realize now that I omitted this in my description, but the difficulty with doing a typeahead search in my case is that the hierarchy defines the items in my structure. I suppose that my example wasn't quite representative enough because it's actually more like traits. So maybe it's [music] -> [rap] -> [east coast]. People might not search "east coast" or think of it, and I don't have an advanced enough search to be able to parse something like "east coast rap" into the above.

Comment: I had explored showing the hierarchy of items, like saying "music -> rap -> east coast" and "music -> rap -> west coast" as the items in a flat list, but then it gets difficult to find the differences visually. And it could get crowded on small screens.

Comment: It's also probably important to mention that this is a *best fit* type search. They can find the most similar item to what they're looking for, not necessarily an exact match.

Comment: It'd be advantageous to work with the real data and understand what the challenge is.

Comment: Sure. I'm working with the [USDA nutrient database](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/list), and generally would recommend the best fit data when people are selecting things. That is, if you have honeycrisp apples and the closest thing is gala, you'll want to just select gala because it's quite similar.

Comment: Is it some type of food diary?

Comment: That type of feature, yeah. I'm working on a component I'll use in multiple places like that.

Comment: I use a food diary on my mobile and the example I've posted above would be a version of it, I believe it would work, but its up to you.

Comment: I'll see if I can restructure my data to work with this, thanks!